# keystone drop the database when used with child process

Tags: mongodb, child-process, keystonejs

Here is my problem.
When I use the following code in my program:

`var spawn = require ('child_process').spawn;
...
var child = spawn ('node', ['my_program2', '...'], {stdio : ['ipc', fd_out, fd_err]});`

my database is dropped.
The father program and the son program, use keystone.

I chose to use child_process because I have to have two different programs, the second launched by the first, and I have to listen to different socket.

Anyone know how to set keystone to avoid emptying the database or how to use the two programs with just one instance of keystone?

I thank you in advance.

ps: the Database I use is mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, error of mine ...
When creating a list, we use new keystone.List(), but when using it, it is keystone.list
Caps can lead to confusion.